# Why is delete_at not removing elements at supplied index?

Tags: ruby

I have a `Worker` and `Job` example, where each `Job` has an expensive/slow `perform` method.

If I have 10 `Jobs` in my `@job_table` I'd like to work them off in batches of 5, each within their own process. 
After the 5 processes (one batch) have exited I'm trying to remove those `Jobs` from the `@job_table` with [`delete_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at).

*I'm observing something unexpected in my implementation (see code below) though:*

```
jobs: 
[#<Job:0x007fd2230082a8 @id=0>,
 #<Job:0x007fd223008280 @id=1>,
 #<Job:0x007fd223008258 @id=2>,
 #<Job:0x007fd223008208 @id=3>,
 #<Job:0x007fd2230081e0 @id=4>,
 #<Job:0x007fd2230081b8 @id=5>,
 #<Job:0x007fd223008190 @id=6>,
 #<Job:0x007fd223008168 @id=7>,
 #<Job:0x007fd223008140 @id=8>,
 #<Job:0x007fd223008118 @id=9>]
```

This is the `@job_table` before the first batch is run. I see that `Jobs` 0-4 have run and exited successfully (omitted output here).
So I'm calling `remove_batch_1` and would expect jobs 0-4 to be removed from the `@job_table`, but this is what I'm observing instead:

```
jobs: 
[#<Job:0x007fd223008280 @id=1>,
 #<Job:0x007fd223008208 @id=3>,
 #<Job:0x007fd2230081b8 @id=5>,
 #<Job:0x007fd223008168 @id=7>,
 #<Job:0x007fd223008118 @id=9>]
```

I've logged the `i` parameter in the method and it returns 0-4. But it looks like `delete_at` is removing other jobs (0,2,4,6,8).

I also wrote another method for removing a batch `remove_batch_0` which uses [`slice!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice-21) and behaves as expected.

```
BATCH_SIZE = 5 || ENV['BATCH_SIZE']

class Job
  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
  end

  def perform
    puts "Job #{@id}> Start!"
    sleep 1
    puts "Job #{@id}> End!"
  end
end

class Worker
  def initialize
    @job_table = []
    fill_job_table
    work_job_table
  end

  def fill_job_table
    10.times do |i|
      @job_table << Job.new(i)
    end
  end

  def work_job_table
    until @job_table.empty?
      puts "jobs: "
      pp @job_table

      work_batch
      Process.waitall

      remove_batch_1
    end
  end

  def work_batch
    i = 0
    while (i < @job_table.length && i < BATCH_SIZE)
      fork { @job_table[i].perform }
      i += 1
    end
  end

  def remove_batch_1
    i = 0
    while (i < @job_table.length && i < BATCH_SIZE)
      @job_table.delete_at(i)
      i += 1
    end
  end

  def remove_batch_0
    @job_table.slice!(0..BATCH_SIZE-1)
  end
end

Worker.new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `delete_at` in a while loop. Let's see what happens:

Image you have an array `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and you call:

```
 (1..3).each { |i| array.deleted_at(i) }
```

In the first iteration you will delete the first element from the array, the array will look like this after this step: `[1,2,3,4,5]` In the next iteration you will delete the second element, what leads to `[1,3,4,5]`. Then you delete the third: `[1,3,5]`

You might want to use [`Array#shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) instead:

```
def remove_batch_1
  @job_table.shift(BATCH_SIZE)
end
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thank you.